# Show main menu in Foundation 6 Off canvas by loading a different twig template

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

How do I load my Primary menu in my Foundation Off canvas region `off-canvas position-left`?

In `menu--main.html.twig` I have below structure for my desktop menu:

```
<div class="top-bar nav-desktop show-for-small-only">
  <div class="wrap">

    <div class="top-bar-left">
      <a class="site-logo" href="/site">Griffioen</a>
    </div>

    <div class="top-bar-right">
      {{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I hide it on mobile with the Foundation class `show-for-small-only`. But now it's hiding the **main menu** also in the `off-canvas position-left`.

Is there somehow a way to load another twig template from the main menu in the Off canvas region e.g. `menu--off-canvas.html.twig`? Then I am able to hide the desktop menu `menu--main.html.twig` and show the Off Canvas menu `menu--off-canvas.html.twig`?